# Find the nth smallest number

Tags: java

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NthSmallest{
  public static void main (String [] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the size of the array");

    final int N = 15;
    int n  = input.nextInt();

    int array[]  = new int [N];
    System.out.println("enter 15 number ");

    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) {
      array[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println(findNthSmallest(array, n  ));
  }

  public static int findNthSmallest( int array[], int n  ){
    int i, j,t=0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
      for(j = 1; j < (n-i); j++){
        if(array[j-1] > array[j]){
          t = array[j-1];
          array[j-1]=array[j];
          array[j]=t;
        }
      }
    }

    return array[n-1];
  }
}
```

When I want to find `fifthSmallestNumber` and enter 5 as the first input, the program finds the number five not fifth smallest number. How can I fix it?

Comment: "There is no error". I think you mean "there are no compilation errors". Bugs, like finding the wrong number, are errors.

Comment: I think there is some confusion about what you are asked to do. If n is the size of the array (which, in fact, it isn't in your code, but your code asks the user for the size of the array!) then to find the nth smallest number is identical to finding the largest number. Surely the task is not that simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop, it should be :

```
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      for(j = 1; j < (array.length-i); j++){
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) The problem has fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static int findNthSmallest(int[] array, int n) {
    Arrays.sort(array);
    return array[n-1];
}
```

Comment: I can't use any sort method from the java library. This is my homework we are not allowed to use it.